# use base64_encode in tpl file

Tags: php, base64, smarty

I am newbie in smarty and trying to do something in it.

Now, I have following code in my login.tpl (smarty template) file

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirectTo" value="{$smarty.get.redirectTo}" />
```

As per my little understanding whatever the GET data coming from url is putted into the value
of hidden fields.

Now, I want to encode this url data using base64_encode function. But how can I encode it using base64_encode because its not php code. I also tried like this :

```
{base64_encode($smarty.get.redirectTo)}
```

But this is not working.

Need help...

Thanks

Comment: Eat, ate eaten.  Put, put, put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the output to a smarty variable before like

```
$smarty->assign('yourVarforsmarty', base64_encode($yourVar));
```

and than in smarty template use simply

```
{$yourVarforsmarty}
```

OR

call php function like this

```
{php} 
  $temp = base64_encode($smarty.get.redirectTo); 
{/php}

<input type="hidden" name="redirectTo" value="{$temp}" />
```

Comment: not working anymore on new versions

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a modifier somewhere where $smarty class is created in your PHP:

`$smarty->registerPlugin("modifier",'base64_encode',  'base64_encode');`

and then call it in TPL:

`{$string_to_encode|base64_encode}`